# Using CreateFile To Access a Drive Partition

Tags: c++, winapi, createfile

I have admin rights and have no problem getting a valid handle and ultimately reading an entire hard drive via:

```
IntPtr handle = CreateFile(@"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

I can also get a valid handle when I try to open a directory of that drive:

```
IntPtr handle = CreateFile(@"\\.\Z:\\", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

But I cannot get a valid handle when I try to simply open a partition of that drive:

```
IntPtr handle = CreateFile(@"\\.\Z:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

`GetLastWin32Error` returns access denied (5).

Of course if I offline the drive, then I get "`The system cannot find the file specified`."
I've tried everything I could think of with different partitions, different options etc. to no available.

Comment: Hey, so have you found a way to open a drive partition?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself.  Let me correct myself in pointing out that CreateFile(@"\.\Z:" is opening a Volume, not necessarily a partition.  However, I could not even open a volume.

Until I added FILE_SHARE_WRITE to the options as follows:

IntPtr handle = CreateFile(@"\.\Z:", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

That was the key to getting a valid handle.  This is certainly not intuitive!

Why this should be the case is only known by Microsoft I guess.

Comment: there's probably a typo, the file name should be ´@"\\.\Z:"´
Furthermore, I found out that it is important(!!) to omit a trailing slash after the drive letter ´C:´ not ´C:\´

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that the documentation of `CreateFile` says the following about `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`:

> Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request write access.
>
> Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they request write access.
>
> If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for write access or has a file mapping with write access, **the function fails**.